# apidiscovery-1.0 on Liberty Beta

Tags: java, swagger, websphere-liberty

I have an app that has been running for a while.  I decided to investigate Swagger.. and happily found out that the Liberty beta has Swagger integrated.

I decided to try it out.. but I can't seem to get anything discovered...

My features..

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
    <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>

    <!-- The following features are in beta! -->
    <feature>bluemixUtility-1.0</feature>
    <feature>cloudant-1.0</feature>
    <feature>logstashCollector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>logmetCollector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>osgiAppConsole-1.0</feature>
    <feature>osgiBundle-1.0</feature>
    <feature>passwordUtilities-1.0</feature>
    <feature>wsAtomicTransaction-1.2</feature>
    <feature>apiDiscovery-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

My apiDiscovery definition

```
<apiDiscovery>

    <webModuleDoc contextRoot="/MYCONTEXTROOT" docURL="/swagger.json" enabled="true"/>  

</apiDiscovery>
```

But .. Nothing. I have verified that the IBM APIs are found by visiting

https://localhost:9443/ibm/api/explorer

My app has @Path and so on.. and according to [this](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_api_discovery.html?lang=en) that's all I need.

From that site..

> The product scans all classes in the web application for JAX-RS and
>   Swagger annotations, searching for classes with **@Path**, @Api, and
>   @SwaggerDefinition annotations. The product also automatically
>   generates a corresponding Swagger document during the web application
>   deployment or startup.

Am I missing something?

Cheers!

James

Comment: Also tried this... 

New Liberty beta functionality

JAX-RS 1.1/2.0 and Swagger annotation support

We now support auto-generation of Swagger definitions from JAX-RS and Swagger annotations! 

This is a very important feature, since it supports the famous bottom-up development where the documentation comes from the code itself. Just enable apiDiscovery-1.0, drop your JAX-RS application into the dropins directory (with either jaxrs-1.1 or jaxrs-2.0 enabled) and watch your APIs come out inside /ibm/api/explorer

https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2016/02/17/exposing-liberty-rest-apis-swagger/

Comment: Version: 

Launching defaultServer (WebSphere Application Server 2016.3.0.0/wlp-1.0.12.20160305-0200)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...

Seems that there were 2 issues I had where I was doing this..

```
@POST @Path("/widget/{name}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createWidget(  @Context HttpServletRequest request, String bodyText )
```

{name} was not used as a PathParam.  I guess it was once :-)  Had that in 2 places.  **It does appear in the log.. just not right away.** Fixed those and it worked perfectly.

James

Answer (score 0):

If you have JAX-RS annotations you don't need to use the "webModuleDoc" attribute in server.xml.  That attribute is meant for cases where you have a pre-generated swagger.json or swagger.yaml file, either in another location within your application (such as /swagger.json), or from a remote URL, such as a document repository.

So if you have annotations it's all done automatically, without the need for webModuleDoc.

The following log spec will reveal the swagger document that we generated for each of the aplications:

```
<logging traceSpecification="RESTAPIDiscovery=finest"/>
```

A common usage error is having 2 methods with the same name within the same jaxrs application.  As per the Swagger model, Liberty uses the method names as operation IDs, so they must be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the response... Appreciated

Comment: @ArthurDM does the 2 method with the same name policy include implemented interfaces used for JAX-RS Resources?

Comment: @austinbruch the latest version of Liberty (16004, or any of the recent Beta drivers) no longer has that limitation, so you can have methods with the same name.